# Rails polymorphic association accepts_nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I currently a polymorphic association set up like this

```
class Reading < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :audio, as: :audioable
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :audio
end

class Audio < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :audioable, polymorphic: true
end
```

In my RSPEC test, I have this set up

```
@reading = attributes_for(:reading, creator: @user, body: "who let the dogs out? Must be me\n\nMeMeMe")
@reading[:audio_attributes] = attributes_for(:audio)
```

However, I get the following errors when posting this `@reading` to the `reading#create` controller

```
{:errors=>{:"audio.audioable"=>["must exist"]}}
```

For non-polymorphic associations I've gotten it to create both the parent and nested resources using `inverse_of` but I'm not sure how to do it for polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 0):

`inverse_of` can't be used for polymorphic associations, have you looked at [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) it could be a good solution depending of what you are trying to achieve